# How stop user in client-side from using MySQL commands when set password to expire from server side during client log in?

Tags: mysql, client-server, mysql-5.7, mysql-cli

1. I use **root** to log in on local ***MySQL Server Machine*** [192.168.156.33](http://192.168.156.33) and create new user **test** for anonymous host **%** `CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
2. I use **client machine** to log in with user **test** `mysql -u test -h 192.168.156.33 -p`
3. I use **server machine** again to set **test** password account to **expire** by using `ALTER USER 'test'@'%' PASSWORD EXPIRE;` and use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` Notice that user **test** still log in on client machine
4. User **test** in client machine still can use command: `SHOW DATABASES, USE, SELECT,...` without show warning to change password
5. After I use command `\r` or (`exit` and log in back), and try to use command, it show warning to change password like normal

What I want is: **How to stop user from use commands when set password to expire and show warning to them to change password without reconnect to server?**

[image: Picture]

Comment: Would it be an option to kick the user? (Forcing him to reconnect, then he has to change the password)

Comment: *How to stop user from use commands when set password to expire and show warning to them to change password without reconnect to server?* Noway, password expire is checked only during the authentication. And you shouldn't force reconnection, it may in theory break current user's operation and cause logical data incorrectness.

Comment: Hello @Akina, if I don't do this, users can do something on sensitive data in our databases without permission. I test it also on GRANT and REVOKE privileges, but I test on this expire password first and I encounter the problem.

Comment: Hello @Solarflare, yes it would be that. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: *if I don't do this, users can do something on sensitive data in our databases without permission.* No. During authentication the user had the permission, hence the session obtains this permission. The fact that you have changed the permission for a user does not change the permission of the session. And the session may access the object which you had "protected".

Comment: @Akina How can I can session permission?